# PIN Transfer not working in thales hsm

Tags: hsm

I am using PIN transfer functionality in HSM Thales, using function `'TW'` to transfer pin from one PVK to other. Business logic is given below,

cards are getting migrated from one host to other, since the host is different the PVK is different. both the current host and target host keys are configured in HSM at target system.

i need to generate new pin offset using the transfer keys option. the logic is,

1) supply old card nbr, new card number, old PVK , new PVK , old decimilization table, new decimilization table and call HSM with function code tw and HSM should respond with TX code with new pin offset.

while calling HSM, i am getting return code 15, invalid input, which is very generic.  what would be the cause of the issue. message is given below.

```
*** HSM CALL DETAILS                                               *** 
*** HSTWZLK ACCT NUMBER          :887000001273                     *** 
*** PVK OLD                      :610XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX *** 
*** PVK NEW                      :F92XXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX *** 
*** DECIMILI TBL OLD             :FD64FC3FAD504BB3                 *** 
*** DECIMILI TBL NEW             :FD64FC3FAD504BB3                 *** 
*** OLD PIN OFFSET               :8278                             *** 
*** HSTWZLK PIN OFFSET           :8278FFFFFFFF                     *** 
*** PIN DATA OLD                 :XXXXXX0000012739                 *** 
*** PIN DATA NEW                 :XXXXXX0000012739                 ***
```

Comment: 'TW' seems to be a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HSM got decrypted PIN data in unexpected [PIB Block Formats](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/261-complete-list-of-pin-blocks-in-payments).
Your clear PIN format must be one of them.

You must be sure that PVKs are encrypted with same LMK(thats LMK that HSM commands run )

Answer (score 0):

'TW' command does not exists. It is not possible to translate pinoffset as pinoffset generation process is lossy process in which only first 4 numeric digits are taken from encrypted data and rest is discarded.

But to solve your problem, you can translate your key to new HSM instead of trying to translate offsets.

Answer (score -1):

'TW' doesnt seem to be a supported command. Check CC, CA, JE, JG and CI options.